# How to put the output report of the flay gem in a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to find the code duplication in my code. For that I am using Flay gem. Although it is very tedious to view it in the terminal. How to put the result generated by the Flay gem in a file in a report format?

I tried `-o` option, but it is not working.

I am using flay 2.5.0.

Comment: That is more of a question with the shell/terminal. Pipe the result to a file.

Comment: Thanx. But the format of the report remains the same as it is in the terminal. I want to view it in some formatted view. Like the report of the Brakeman gem.

Comment: @RichaSinha you can filter you output with bash/zsh/other shell methods.

Comment: It is not filtering that i want. I want the result generated in a file in the form of a report.

Comment: Please see the [Brakeman Gem report](http://railscasts.com/episodes/358-brakeman?view=asciicast) sample. I want the result in a similar way. Is there any way to do so?